# Featured Image and Facebook

Tags: facebook, social-sharing

So I've got a problem. My single post page has a full screen image with an H1 over it for the title. That image is brought in using the featured image. However, when posting this blog post to say Facebook, the facebook post uses this featured image except it obviously doesn't have that H1 title over it.

So... I'm kinda stuck here and looking for a solution.

I want to keep the blog post featured image and H1 for SEO purposes, but I also don't want Facebook (or twitter/linkedin) to be pulling just that image without a title. I'd theoretically like to use a different image for Facebook than this featured image. How would I do that?

Comment: Are you using Jetpack to generate your open graph tags?

Comment: @vancoder No, not using jetpack.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I've done this before - albeit in broad terms. I've used the [Multiple Thumbnails](https://en-ca.wordpress.org/plugins/multiple-post-thumbnails/) plugin to generate a secondary image meta box for the post. I used Jetpack to generate the Open Graph tags that Facebook looks for. This allows us to [create a jetpack_images_get_images filter](http://jetpack.me/tag/image/), and tell Jetpack exactly what image to define in the OG tags.